# SugarCRM Home Page URL

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am using sugarCRM Open Source Application for my own purpose.
When I click the Home link the above URL is like:

`ajaxUILoc=index.php?module=Home&action=index&ParentTab=sales`

How can I find out the flow of code using the above url. I have verified the sugarCRM developers guide regarding the url, but I cannot get the solution.  How they call the functions or classes using like this.

Actually why I am asking is I want to modify the existing code to add some extra modules.
I am struggling for last one week without solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ajaxUILoc=index.php?module=Home&action=index&ParentTab=sales`

That is saying you are in the `sales` Tab and on the 'Index' Page of the `Home` Module.

Firstly there is a `modules` directory in the root of the application inside which is a directory for each module, secondly for customisations there is a `custom` directory in the root of the application, where is generally all custom code is placed to make SugarCRM upgrade safe. There is a `customCode` variable you can add for placing custom code in the custom files.

Example:

`'customCode'=>'{if $surrent_user->user_name==\'admin\'} .....some code...... {/if} {if $current_user->user_name!=\'admin\'} <input name="assigned_user_name" value="{$fields.assigned_user_name.value}" readonly="readonly"> {/if}',`

The SugarCRM forums can be quite good http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums